# Add incremented number to AD attribute based on last value

Tags: powershell, active-directory, increment

I'm trying to use PowerShell to search the AD attribute `otherTelephone`, and if the value is null then add the next number in the sequence.

For instance, if I add a new user called John, I'd like PowerShell to check AD and see that the last `otherTelephone` number used was 999 so it'll auto add 1000 for John.

So far I've managed to export a list of users in AD along with their respective `otherTelephone` numbers:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties otherTelephone |
  select name, @{L='otherTelephone'; E={$_.otherTelephone[0]}}, |
  Export-Csv c:\aduser.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: You could first get  all numbers,  pipe them to sort-object, select the highest, increment by 1 then set it for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paul suggested in the comments to your question: read the phone numbers from AD, get the highest number, and increment it.

```
$nextPhoneNumber = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties otherTelephone |
                     ? { $_.otherTelephone } |
                     select -Expand otherTelephone |
                     % { [int]$_ } | sort -Desc | select -First 1
$nextPhoneNumber++
```

Explanation:

- `? { $_.otherTelephone }`: Ensure that only objects with a non-empty attribute are processed.
- `select -Expand otherTelephone`: Expand the attribute so that you get a stream of phone numbers. This also takes care of multiple numbers assigned to a user (the attribute is multi-valued).
- `% { [int]$_ }`: Convert each telephone number from a string to an integer, so they can be sorted numerically.
- `sort -Desc`: Sort the list in descending order (first number is highest).
- `select -First 1`: Select the first number from the list and discard the rest.
- `$nextPhoneNumber++`: increment the number by 1.

If you need to do this for all existing users that don't already have the `otherTelephone` attribute populated, you could do something like this:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties otherTelephone

$nextPhoneNumber = $users | ? { $_.otherTelephone } |
                     select -Expand otherTelephone |
                     % { [int]$_ } | sort -Desc | select -First 1

$users | ? { -not $_.otherTelephone } | % {
  $nextPhoneNumber++
  Set-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Replace @{
    'otherTelephone' = $nextPhoneNumber
  }
}
```